# Journals for undergraduates

Tags: mathematics-education, journals, math-communication, soft-question, big-list

Are there math journals that are aimed for undergraduates? I don't mean here journals where students can publish their papers, but journals that publish introductory articles that an undergraduate can read without too much sweating, preferably when he gets bored or tired from his assignments and wants to read something different. What journals do you recommend to undergrads to read on a regular basis?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7329/math-journal-for-high-school-students, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4807/which-magazines-should-i-read

Comment: The trouble is that you can't read them unless you have an account...

Comment: You CAN read them if you walk to the library...

Answer (score 23):

[The American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly.html).

See also [this](http://www.york.cuny.edu/~malk/biblio/journals-biblio.html) list.

Comment: I wouldn't say the Monthly is *aimed* at undergraduates.

Comment: I would say it is _also_ aimed at undergraduates.

Answer (score 21):

As the name suggests, the [College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj.html)

Comment: ...and, in alternate months, *Mathematics Magazine*.  As far as "age of audience" is concerned, the three MAA jounals can be ordered: CMJ < MM < AMM .


Answer (score 19):

The [mathematical intelligencer](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/283) can be interesting.

Answer (score 12):

The journal "[Morfismos](http://chucha.math.cinvestav.mx/morfismos/indenglish.html)" published by CINVESTAV, Mexico, is aimed at undergraduate and graduate students. Although some articles are in Spanish, they publish fairly good expository articles in English. For example, there is a survey on the recent solution of the Kervaire invariant one problem  in [this issue](http://chucha.math.cinvestav.mx/morfismos/v13n2/index.html).

Answer (score 12):

MAA's [Mathematics Magazine](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mathmag.html) is a reasonable expository journal.

Answer (score 9):

Speaking of non-English language publications, Сборник [Математическое Просвещение](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/matpros.html) and [Kvant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvant_(magazine)) are terrific (and often overlooked) Russian journal, aimed primarily at undergraduates.

Answer (score 6):

If you read German, you can also try [Elemente der Mathematik](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=em), which also have some articles in english.

Answer (score 6):

If you read German, you might also be interested in [die Wurzel](http://www.wurzel.org/).

Answer (score 6):

There are two such journals published in India:

1. [Mathematics Newsletter](http://www.ramanujanmathsociety.org/mnl.html) published by the Ramanujan Mathematical Society.
2. [Resonance](http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/) (journal of science education) published by the Indian Academy of Sciences, which is a general science journal, but usually has a maths article in each issue.

Answer (score 4):

This one is nice: [$\pi$ in the  sky](http://www.pims.math.ca/resources/publications/pi-sky).

Answer (score 4):

[The Harvard College Mathematics Review](http://thehcmr.org) was another interesting venture, but it seems to be discontinued as of now.

Comment: I believe it's just on haitus; I'm still on the mailing list, and have been receiving emails lately.

Comment: Looks like it really has vanished.

Comment: At https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/index.html you'll find the issues from 2007, 2008, 2011, and 2012. It appears that that's all there is.

Answer (score 4):

The MAA quarterly [Math Horizons](http://www.maa.org/mathhorizons/) is explicitly aimed at undergraduates interested in mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

``Plus"- an online-only British journal (similar to Math Horizons):

http://plus.maths.org/content/

From their home page: ``Plus provides articles and podcasts on any aspect of mathematics, covering topics as diverse as art, medicine, cosmology and sport, a news section, showing how recent news stories were often based on some underlying piece of maths that never made it to the newspapers, reviews of popular maths books, and puzzles for you to sharpen your wits. We have a regular interview with someone in a maths-related career, showing the wide range of uses maths gets put to in the real world."

The intended audience is not limited to math undergraduates; science undergrads would find something interesting there, too. Some articles can be accessible even to high-school students.

And for those who read Polish, there is ``Delta" (which I used to read regularly in the paper version as an undergrad):

http://www.deltami.edu.pl/

The 01/2013 issue contains e.g. an article on William Thurston and geometrization conjecture (by Zdzislaw Pogoda).

Answer (score 3):

A journal similar to the American Mathematical Monthly, but in french, shall be launched by the SMF (french mathematical society) but I do not know when exactly nor what will be the title.

Comment: Has it been created since your post?..)

Comment: @Olga: no, unfortunately the project seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: @ Benoît Kloeckner This is sad, maybe the good idea will come back in some years. People should be more motivated!

Answer (score 2):

In the applied field there is [SIAM Undergraduate Research Online](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/). Although it is mainly for for research papers written by undergraduates they write that

> "Outstanding expository papers written for the undergraduate audience by a faculty member or researcher featuring a survey topic or a subject of historical interest will also be considered."

An example is the paper "Moving Forward by Traveling in Circles" from the [first volume](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue1/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you understand french, "Quadrature" is also a good magazine which for instance contains sections about counter examples and history of mathematics. Recently a special issue about Poincaré has been published.

http://www.quadrature.info/index.php?page=002

Answer (score 1):

If you can read Japanese, [数学セミナー](https://www.nippyo.co.jp/shop/magazines/latest/4.html) is quite good. I knew the work of Thurston, the history of galoia and new trend of mathematic world by this journal.

Answer (score 1):

If you read French, you should certainly look at this site : http://images.math.cnrs.fr/?lang=fr
This was first aimed at teachers and large audience interested in maths but on practice this is read by mathematicians themselves and graduate/undergraduate students. Lots of beautiful math in there!

Answer (score 0):

[The Mathematics Student Journal](https://www.indianmathsociety.org.in/ms.htm)  of the Indian Mathematical society has some articles which are accessible for undergraduates.

Answer (score 0):

[Undergraduate Mathematics and its Application (UMAP)](https://www.comap.com/product/periodicals/)

Answer (score 0):

In [Mathematics 4 Maryams](https://maths4maryams.org/) you can find hundred years of Iranian expository mathematics magazines. They are all in Farsi. But, even with no knowledge of Farsi, you can literally see the extraordinary diversity and evolution of the magazines in the last hundred years. Many of the most influential ones are published by the students of universities, among them Mathematics Magazine of Sharif University (where Maryam Mirzakhani got her first degree), and Mathematics  Magazine of Tehran University (where Caucher Birkar got his first degree.)